# Can I move Xcode and Android Studio to SD card

Tags: applications, storage, sd-card

I'm planning to buy a 64GB SD card to supplement the storage on my MacBook Air 128GB (early 2015)

I wanted to know if I can move my Xcode and android studio to it as both have them take a significant part of the memory.

If this can happen, I wanted to know how can I move these two to the SD card. I'm fairly new to macOS and have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I gotta ask.... Why would you get the entry level MBA which, for all intents and purposes, is just barely enough for consumer use, to do dev work?  If two apps put such a dent in your storage, was this the *right* Mac to get?

Answer (score 4):

Can you? Yes.

Is it wise? Perhaps not.

Flash storage is notoriously frail. Once it fails, that's, it, it's gone, usually taking everything on there with it.

The adage "Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary" is not one to take lightly.

Other than that - it will run like molasses from an SD card.

Flash on USB sticks/SD cards is not the same as on an SSD drive - this has a better explanation than I could possibly compete with -
[SuperUser - What's the technical difference between a flash drive and an SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/919058/whats-the-technical-difference-between-a-flash-drive-and-an-ssd)

In the end, it’s your choice what you store externally, so if other things are more vital than code, keep them on the internal storage. If code is the priority, move photos or music or video files to SD storage.

Comment: Are you saying that the internal storage in their laptop isn't also flash storage?

Comment: All flash isn't born equal - this has a good explanation - https://superuser.com/questions/919058/whats-the-technical-difference-between-a-flash-drive-and-an-ssd

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can move these apps to SDCard by directly dragging these from your Applications directory to destination on your SD card.

Applications can generally run from anywhere. Some support files get stored in your home folder regardless of the location of the document or app.

Comment: Will Xcode work there I think there might be hard coded paths

Comment: The path from where Xcode is running will play no impact on the apps development.

Comment: Even for the include and library paths for building and for simulators?

Comment: @user151019 that is tied to the location of the system and home folder and not stored on the App bundle.